# Storing words read from a file excluding special characters

Tags: c, getchar

I am having trouble storing the strings correctly in this bit of code. I am excluding any special characters using isalnum(). The issue I am trying to overcome is that this method is also storing empty strings as well. I'm trying to find a way to iterate over special characters without storing them into a string.

```
char* readWords(void) {
  char str[max];
  int c;
  int i = 0;

  while ((c = getchar()) != EOF){
    if(isalnum(c)){
      str[i] = c;
      i++;
    } else {
      return stringStore(str,i); // i is the length of the string
      i = 0;
    }
  }
  return NULL;
}
```

Comment: `if(i!=0)return stringStore(str,i);` also `if(i!=0)return stringStore(str,i); else return NULL;`

Comment: That did the trick. Thanks! I've been at it too long I think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if(i!=0)return stringStore(str,i);
```

also

```
if(i!=0)return stringStore(str,i); else return NULL;
```

–  BLUEPIXY